# Testing a private method in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection, mockito, mockk

I'm trying to test a private method which takes the below parameters as input :

**ClassToBeTested**

```
delete(
        someId1: String,
        aList: List<CustomObject>,
        someId2: String,
        someId3: String,
        someId4: String
) : Long? {
}
```

**TestClass**

```
val method = ClassToBeTested.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("delete", String::class.java,
    List::class.java, String::class.java, String::class.java, String::class.java)
```

```
method.isAccessible = true
val testId = method.invoke(ClassToBeTested, someId1, aList, someId2, someId3, someId4)
```

I end up getting the below error :

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:`

`ClassToBeTested$Companion.delete(java.lang.String, java.util.Arrays$ArrayList, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`

When I tried changing the above method declaration as :

```
val method = ClassToBeTested.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("delete", String::class.java,
    List<CustomObject>::class.java, String::class.java, String::class.java, String::class.java)
```

I get the below error :
`Kotlin: Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal`

Is there anyway we can test the private function which takes a parameter of List of Custom Objects?

Comment: your first method fails because you are calling the delete method on the companion object instead of an instance of the class. But please clarify why you need reflection in your question, because there is nothing indicating that need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use reflection for this. Simply make the method `internal` and call it directly from your tests. You can even add an annotation like `@VisibleForTesting` or `@TestOnly`, those are available in various libraries.

Comment: Thank you making it as an internal method resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kotlin's [declaredMemberFunctions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/declared-member-functions.html) property to find it based on its name alone:

```
data class CustomObject(val id: String)

class ClassToBeTested {
    private fun delete(
        someId1: String,
        aList: List<CustomObject>,
        someId2: String,
        someId3: String,
        someId4: String
    ): Long? {
        return someId1.toLongOrNull()
    }
}

class SampleTest {

    @Test
    fun test1() {
        val instance = ClassToBeTested()
        val method = instance::class.declaredMemberFunctions.first { it.name == "delete" }.apply { isAccessible = true }
        val result = method.call(instance, "1", emptyList<CustomObject>(), "2", "3", "4")
        assertEquals(1L, result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marvin for your answer, but when I try to test it in the above way i get the below error : 


`io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: ClassToBeTested(#3).delete$PackageName(someId1, [], someId2, someId3, someId4)`

`

Comment: That has nothing to do with your initial question. This error comes from your mocking framework. And if you have a mock, then why do you need to call the private method at all?